# Removing Query String from URL by using jquery (working with issue)

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my website blog pages added query string in that page URL. I wanted to remove the query string from the URL. So i used to go with jquery and i wrote and added into my scripts. It removes the query string but keep on refreshing the page upto nth time. I used to "one" jquery method. That also doesn't work.

Can you help me

My Script is

```
jQuery(document).one('ready',function(){
    window.location.href = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
});
```

Comment: You need to check if `window.location.href` has `?` first.

Comment: use `.indexOf()` to check.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

setting a value to window.location.href will reload the page. Try this:

```
    var url = window.location.href;
    var a = url.indexOf("?");
    var b =  url.substring(a);
    var c = url.replace(b,"");
    url = c;
```

Comment: It is just removing the query params from var URL, not actually updating the browser url

Answer (score 25):

```
var uri = window.location.href.toString();
if (uri.indexOf("?") > 0) {
    var clean_uri = uri.substring(0, uri.indexOf("?"));
    window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, clean_uri);
}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could put an explanatory text along with the code, to improve your answer, making it more helpful to all users

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer!

Answer (score 6):

> keep on refreshing the page upto nth time.

This is because you are not checking whether the URL has a query string or not. So it is an infinite refresh.

You can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (window.location.href.indexOf('?') > -1) {
        window.location.href = window.location.pathname;
    }
});
```

> **Edit 1:** Is it possible to remove query string without page refresh?

You can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (window.location.href.indexOf('?') > -1) {
        history.pushState('', document.title, window.location.pathname);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes its working. However it get refreshing one time. Is it possible to remove query string without page refresh?

Comment: @Beginner hey this second script is cool!But i still see for about second the query :(  also does the query still holds values?

Comment: @IngusGraholskis You will, until the DOM has been loaded. No, it won't be available client side.

Answer (score 0):

So if the href is different to the hostname + pathname it has an query. So remove it and refresh the page once:

```
jQuery(document).one('ready',function(){
    if(window.location.href != window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname) {
        window.location.href = window.location.pathname;
    }
});
```